# Is there a way to access the Model's data as variables in Razor (not as Html.DisplayFor())?

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am trying to access the current Model's data in a Razor file, but not as `Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)`. I would actually like to store the Model's data in a variable like: `var Name = Model.Name`. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean like `@{ var modelValue = Model.value; }`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Xipooo: Please, make answer from your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Razor syntax to embed C# directly into a Razor view.

```
@{ var modelValue = Model.value; }
```

Then you can use the variable elsewhere in your view:

```
<p>Value: @modelValue</p>
```